# Web service with Rails and Device, how to logout after the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, devise

I am doing a Web service with Rails using device module nammed "TokenAuthenticatable"

I have activated it and now I can log myself through the webservice by giving an authentication token like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/?auth_token=OyJOIOjje4_hkjdd

Logged user : Vincent
```

The thing is, if I go on this url after that :

```
http://localhost:3000/

Logged user : Vincent
```

The website still identify me as the user logged with the token that I gave earlier.
I want to be logged only for one request.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller action that deals with your request you need to run

```
sign_out current_user
```